# RNeo4j Error: 400 Bad Request

Tags: neo4j, cypher, r-neo4j

I am not sure why I am getting the error below, but I suppose it's something that I am doing wrong.

First, you can grab my dataset by downloading the file `dataset.r` from [this link](https://gist.github.com/Btibert3/26a3227aae5318173e1e) and loading it into your session with `dget("dataset.r")`.

In my case, I would do `dat = dget("dataset.r")`.

The code below is what I am using to load data into the Neo4j.

```
library(RNeo4j)

graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
graph$version

# sure that the graph is clean -- you should backup first!!!
clear(graph, input = FALSE)

## ensure the constraints
addConstraint(graph, "School", "unitid")
addConstraint(graph, "Topic", "topic_id")

## create the query
## BE CAREFUL OF WHITESPACE between KEY:VALUE pairs for parameters!!!
query = "
MERGE (s:School {unitid:{unitid},
instnm:{instnm},
obereg:{obereg},
carnegie:{carnegie},
applefeeu:{applfeeu},
enrlft:{enrlft},
applcn:{applcn},
admssn:{admssn},
admit_rate:{admit_rate},
ape:{ape},
sat25:{sat25},
sat75:{sat75} })

MERGE (t:Topic {topic_id:{topic_id},
topic:{topic} })

MERGE (s)-[:HAS_TOPIC {score:{score} }]->(t)
"

for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  ## status
  cat("starting row ", i, "\n")
  ## run the query
  cypher(graph, 
         query, 
         unitid = dat$unitid[i],
         instnm = dat$instnm[i],
         obereg = dat$obereg[i],
         carnegie = dat$carnegie[i],
         applfeeu = dat$applfeeu[i],
         enrlft = dat$enrlt[i],
         applcn = dat$applcn[i],
         admssn = dat$admssn[i],
         admit_rate = dat$admit_rate[i],
         ape = dat$apps_per_enroll[i],
         sat25 = dat$sat25[i],
         sat75 = dat$sat75[i],
         topic_id = dat$topic_id[i],
         topic = dat$topic[i],
         score = dat$score[i] )
} #endfor
```

I can successfully load the first 49 records of my dataframe `dat`, but errors out on the 50th row.

This is the error that I recieve:

```
starting row  50 
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error: 400 Bad Request

{"message":"Node 1477 already exists with label School and property \"unitid\"=[110680]","exception":"CypherExecutionException","fullname":"org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExecutionException","stacktrace":["org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_1$spi$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:154)","org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.setProperty(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:121)","org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.spi.UpdateCountingQueryContext$CountingOps.setProperty(UpdateCountingQueryContext.scala:130)","org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.mutation.PropertySetAction.exec(PropertySetAction.scala:51)","org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.mutation.MergeNodeAction$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(MergeNodeAction.scala:80)","org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1
```

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RNeo4j_1.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.1  RJSONIO_1.2-0.2 tools_3.1.0
```

And it's worth noting that I am using Neo4j `2.1.3`.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: __UPDATE__: I threw in a `tryCatch` with a `next` to just skip pass errors.  Here are the rows that had issues:  `50-55,364,661`.   Anything about those rows that catch your eye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with how `MERGE` works. By setting the `score` property within the `MERGE` clause itself here...

```
MERGE (s)-[:HAS_TOPIC {score:{score} }]->(t)
```

...`MERGE` tries to create the entire pattern, and thus your uniqueness constraint is violated. Instead, do this:

```
MERGE (s)-[r:HAS_TOPIC]->(t)
SET r.score = {score}
```

I was able to import all of your data after making this change.